# Camel InOut log both in and out

Tags: java, logging, request, apache-camel, response

I have a route defined as such using a route definition in java:

```
routeDefinition = from("someLocation");
routeDefinition.setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut);
routeDefinition.to("log:camel.logging?level=INFO&showOut=true");
routeDefinition.to("someOtherLocation");
routeDefinition.routeId("someId");
```

The message is consumed and responded to as expected, but when I look at the log the "Out" message is always null i.e.

```
camel - Exchange[ExchangePattern:InOut, BodyType:String, Body:{"timestamp":1393602518590,"headers":{"JMSCorrelationID":"54783292"},"data":{...}}, Out: null]
```

How can I log both the incoming and outgoing message?

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html

Comment: So are you saying it is only logging the exchange to("log... which has no response? If so, how do I log so that I can achieve what I wanted above?

Comment: yeah the log only logs the IN, as there is not OUT as the log does not change/set an OUT message.

Comment: But my other to route ("someOtherLocation") is an JMS broker that responds with a message (i.e. Im trying to use http://camel.apache.org/request-reply.html)). So how can I log both the message that I'm sending and the message the broker replies with?

Comment: Add the log at the END of the route

Comment: I did try that but it still produces the same effect "Out: null". In the logs I do see it correlate the returned message later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about the OUT as the FAQ says.

If you add the log at the end of the route, then what the log output in IN i what is returned to the client.

Its the pipes and filters principle
http://camel.apache.org/pipes-and-filters.html

Comment: I am also trying to do this.
This is the only log I got from camel-rabbitmq's "out" from `InOut` exchange: `2016-02-19 18:27:47.456 DEBUG 8920 --- [abbitMQConsumer] o.a.c.c.rabbitmq.RabbitMQEndpoint        : Sending message to exchange: amq.topic with CorrelationId = null`. I have no idea what it is sending, body, headers, etc.
I think there should be a way (feature request?) to do this in Camel. It should be possible to log the "out" as easily as we log the "in", especially for `InOut` exchanges.